# Would it be possible to use argparse without any flags?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, argparse

Would it be possible to use `argparse` without any flags?

For example, whenever no flags (`-u` or `-i` in this case) are provided, I would like the script to process the first argument `sys.argv[1]` as IP Address.

**The code**

```
import argparse, sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-u')
parser.add_argument('-i')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.i:
    print("IP Address is " + args.i)
elif args.u:
    print("URL is " + args.u)
elif len(sys.argv) > 1: 
    print("IP Address is " + sys.argv[1])
else: 
    print("No arguments ")
```

**Normal output**

```
C:\>python script.py
No arguments

C:\>python script.py 8.8.8.8
usage: script.py [-h] [-u U] [-i I]
script.py: error: unrecognized arguments: 8.8.8.8

C:\>python script.py -i 8.8.8.8
IP Address is 8.8.8.8

C:\>
```

My desired output even if no flags (`-u` or `-i`) provided.

```
C:\>python script.py 8.8.8.8
IP Address is 8.8.8.8

C:\>python script.py -i 8.8.8.8
IP Address is 8.8.8.8
```

If there is better alternative, please let me know.

Comment: What about `python script.py 1.2.3.4 -i 5.6.7.8`? I don't think you can easily do this in `argparse` directly, I'd think about post-processing the object it produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [`ArgumentParser.parse_known_args()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-u')
parser.add_argument('-i')

args, ip = parser.parse_known_args()

if args.i:
    print("IP Address is " + args.i)
elif args.u:
    print("URL is " + args.u)
elif ip:
    print("IP Address is " + ip[0])
else:
    print('No argument provided')
```

---

The disadvantage of this is that it wont show up on the help (unless you include it somewhere or modify the `HelpFormatter`).

---

An other solution is to use a mutually exclusive group with a positional arguments that uses `nargs='?'`:

```
import argparse, sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-u')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()

group.add_argument('-i')
group.add_argument('ip', nargs='?')

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.i:
    print("IP Address is " + args.i)
elif args.ip:
    print("IP Address is " + args.ip)
elif args.u:
    print("URL is " + args.u)
else:
    print('No argument provided')
```

So that when trying to specifying both a positional argument and `-i` you get the error:

```
$ script.py 2.3.4.5 -i 1.2.3.4
usage: script.py [-h] [-u U] [-i I | ip]
p.py: error: argument -i: not allowed with argument ip
```

This will show that you can either use `-i IP` or the positional argument, although the syntax might be slightly difficult to read to people not used to the commandline:

```
$ script.py -h
usage: script.py [-h] [-u U] [-i I | ip]

positional arguments:
  ip

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -u U
  -i I
```

Comment: nice, +1, this looks like the proper way!

Comment: The other disadvantage with `parse_known_arguments()` is that argparse won't error on something that is unrecognized... it'll just pass it on thru.  That's probably not a behavior you really want.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister In the Op's MWE they are not checking IP validity or anything. Obviously you will check the length and parse the IP.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta that's not what I meant.  `parse_known_arguments()` will pass unknown options as arguments rather than an error.  It's not simply a matter of checking IP validity (which none of the solutions offer), it's missing out on the error handling that argparse could get you.  I hope that makes sense.  Try passing `--foo --bar 1.2.3.4` to the `parse_known_args()` and see the behavior.  It won't error on `--foo` and `--bar`... it leaves it up to you to deal with it.  It's nice for writing a wrapper around another tool, but it falls short in other situations.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I don't think you understood how `parse_known_args` works. The arguments that the parsers does not know are provided in the second element of the result. As I said the complete solution will validate the IP hence `--foo` or `--bar` will trigger the validation error. Note that you are probably going to define a `ipaddress` function to specify as `type` of the option and so all you have to do is call that and oyu will get the same error messages.

Comment: I think we're talking past each other.  I know exactly how it works (I've been using argparse for years), but to do the validation work your talking about is part of what you want argparse to help with ("`--foo` is not a valid IP address" versus "hey, I don't know the `--foo` option").  It also doesn't help with more than one argument is being passed on the command line (again, more stuff you have to check rather than argparse helping).  You're kind of using the library, but not to it's full effectiveness.  The exclusion group technique is the much better option, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('-i', dest='type', action='store_const',
                    const='ip', default='ip')
parser.add_argument('-u', dest='type', action='store_const',
                    const='url')

parser.add_argument('location', nargs='?', default=None)

args = parser.parse_args()

if args.location is not None:
    if args.type == 'ip':
        print("IP Address is " + args.location)
    elif args.type == 'url':
        print("URL is " + args.location)
else:
    print("No argument provided")
```

Here we use the options as a way to specify the type and make location a required argument.  The type will default to `ip`, so it gives the default behavior you require, but you can use both `-i` and `-u` to be more explicit.

Comment: this fails with no arguments

Comment: @SergeBallesta perhaps you can explain more what you want?  You can add `nargs='?'`.  I updated the code.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister: Sorry I had not correctly read your answer. Please forget (and forgive) my previous comment.